# How to package a Spring Boot microservice project with Maven in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to build a Spring Boot microservice project with the following structure:

Parent dependency: xx-parent

Child dependencies: xx-xxx, common, xx-xxx

I put all the common dependencies in the common module, and other child modules reference it. Finally, I added the spring-boot-maven-plugin to the pom files of each module that needs to be packaged into a jar, specified the main class, and configured repackage. However, when I packaged the project, I only got a *.jar file without a *.jar.original file. Also, the size of the *.jar file is only a few kb, and it doesn't contain any related dependencies, which means that the repackage goal was not executed. However, there is no error reported in my IntelliJ IDEA. How to solve this problem?

I tried many approaches such as using IntelliJ IDEA's built-in artifact builder, but the resulting artifact had various errors. I also tried using the Maven assemble plugin to build it, but it didn't work either. However, my code has no issues and can run. The problem lies with the errors in the packaged JAR file.

parent:

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xyz.blushyes</groupId>
    <artifactId>edu-video</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <modules>
        <module>edu-user</module>
        <module>edu-course</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>edu-teacher</module>
        <module>feign-api</module>
        <module>edu-order</module>
        <module>edu-message</module>
        <module>edu-login</module>
    </modules>
    <name>edu-video</name>
    <description>edu-video</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>2.6.13</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-cloud-alibaba.version>2021.0.5.0</spring-cloud-alibaba.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--Springboot-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--SpringCloud Alibaba-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-alibaba-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-alibaba.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--SpringCloud-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--Sa-Token-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cn.dev33</groupId>
                <artifactId>sa-token-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>1.34.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

common:

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>edu-video</artifactId>
        <groupId>xyz.blushyes</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>common</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringCloud-alibaba-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--Mybatis-Plus-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--mysql-driver-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

child:

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>edu-video</artifactId>
        <groupId>xyz.blushyes</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>edu-course</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>edu-course</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz.blushyes</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz.blushyes</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>xyz.blushyes.EduCourse</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        
        <finalName>edu-course</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please add the code in the pom.xml file of the parent, child module so that I and others can help you more easily.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have modified the question and added the specific pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, and the reason seems to be that **the dependencies spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-test were not imported**. When I was curious about which dependencies were included in spring-boot-starter and checked it, I might have made a mistake and thought that it included web and test. Then, I deleted web and test, which resulted in the inability to package the project correctly. However, IDEA probably has a caching function, which allowed my project to run normally in IDEA. Later, I deleted my local Maven repository and discovered that web and test were not imported.

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```